# content in tooltip

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I have tooltip(prototip, but it doesnt matter) on my page in javascript and I want when user move on word, where is tooltip, generate tooltip content with string from my proxy-server...so probably when I move on word where is tooltip, javascript send request on proxy server and get response with string content - from this response javascript get this string and show. 
It is possible? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prototip can do that out of the box. Check out the "[**Ajax tooltip**](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip/)" demo. Prototip makes a Ajax request using [**Prototype's Ajax functions**](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax). You just need to build the script that will hand the right content to the request.

Modified example from the Prototip web site:

```
new Tip('myTip', {
  ajax: {
    url: '/include/ajax.php',  // this is where you put the URL of your script
    options: {
    parameters: { parameter1: value1, parameter2: value2} 
     // this is where you put any parameters to the script
    }
  }
});
```